# Start a node from python code - rospy equivalence rosrun - rosgui qt

Tags: roslaunch, rqt-gui, rospy, nodes, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo,

I'm writing a plugin for my rosgui in python. At the moment I'm trying to write an "pressed-button" action which starts a rosnode. I's there a python-command equivalent to "`rosrun pkg node`" or the launch-command "?

Unfortunately  I couldn't find something in the documentations yet.

Thanks for Help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41848/start-a-node-from-python-code---rospy-equivalence-rosrun---rosgui-qt/) by [clotz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2985/clotz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2012-08-20

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the roslaunch api for python ([ref](http://wiki.ros.org/action/fullsearch/roslaunch/API%20Usage?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=linkto%3A%22roslaunch%2FAPI+Usage%22)):

```
import roslaunch

package = 'rqt_gui'
executable = 'rqt_gui'
node = roslaunch.core.Node(package, executable)

launch = roslaunch.scriptapi.ROSLaunch()
launch.start()

process = launch.launch(node)
print(process.is_alive())
process.stop()
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mac137](https://answers.ros.org/users/69218/mac137/) on 2021-02-03**:
@lucasw any idea how to rewrite this code in ROS2 foxy?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As of now the internal [roslaunch python API is unstable](http://ros.org/wiki/roslaunch), but that doesn't mean you can't use it, it just means that there's no guarantee your code is going to continue to work.

Stu Glaser wrote a simple qt-based roslaunch frontend which can be found here: https://kforge.ros.org/rxlaunch/hg/file/9456528dd14c/rxlaunch.py and this gives a simple example of how to do what roslaunch does via Python. (it also has some code taken from roslaunch itself)

If you want to start a node from Python, and want to be able to expect that it will continue to work, you could call out to rosrun with the Python [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

Also, "rosrun" is just a bash script.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2017-05-05**:
Any updates on this yet?